# How to write better code in js calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, logic, calculator

I created simple calculator in js. It works but i have a question. Would i write something better instead many if instruction. I have no idea how can i use functions here.
My code:

```js
const item = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
const screen = document.querySelector('.calculator__screen');
let number = '';
let currentScore = 0;
let currentAction = '';
console.log(item);

item.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (this.innerHTML == '=') {
            switch (currentAction) {
                case '+':
                    screen.innerHTML = currentScore + parseInt(number);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    screen.innerHTML = currentScore - parseInt(number);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    screen.innerHTML = currentScore * parseInt(number);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    screen.innerHTML = currentScore / parseInt(number);
                    break;
            }
        } else if (this.innerHTML == '*') {
            currentAction = '*';
            screen.innerHTML = '*';
            number = parseInt(number);
            currentScore += number;
            number = '';
        } else if (this.innerHTML == '/') {
            currentAction = '/';
            screen.innerHTML = '/';
            number = parseInt(number);
            currentScore += number;
            number = '';
        } else if (this.innerHTML == '-') {
            currentAction = '-';
            screen.innerHTML = '-';
            number = parseInt(number);
            currentScore += number;
            number = '';
        } else if (this.innerHTML == '+') {
            currentAction = '+';
            screen.innerHTML = '+';
            number = parseInt(number);
            currentScore += number;
            number = '';
        } else if (this.innerHTML == 'C') {
            screen.innerHTML = '0';
            currentScore = 0;
            currentAction = '';
            number = '';
        } else {
            number += this.innerHTML;
            screen.innerHTML = number;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: wheat;
  padding: 2em;
}
.calculator__screen {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 0.2em;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 121, 212);
  font-size: 4em;
}
.calculator__body {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 6%;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.calculator__body .item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.calculator__body .item:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="calculator__screen">0</div>
            <div class="calculator__body">
                <div class="item">7</div>
                <div class="item">8</div>
                <div class="item">9</div>
                <div class="item">+</div>
                <div class="item">4</div>
                <div class="item">5</div>
                <div class="item">6</div>
                <div class="item">-</div>
                <div class="item">1</div>
                <div class="item">2</div>
                <div class="item">3</div>
                <div class="item">*</div>
                <div class="item">0</div>
                <div class="item">C</div>
                <div class="item">/</div>
                <div class="item">=</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I feel that it's bad code and here is many repetition. Could anyone help me? And another question do you think simple projects for example like this could I include to my CV because i  try to get a job : trainee frontend developer.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but please read their help first ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what is I did :

```
const item = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
const screen = document.querySelector('.calculator__screen');
let number = '';
let currentScore = 0;
let currentAction = '';



const operators = [
  '*',
  '/',
  '-',
  '+',
  'C'
]
const showResult = (operator )=>{
  if(operators.find( (op) => op == operator) === -1){
    number += this.innerHTML;
    screen.innerHTML = number;
    return
  }
  if(operator == 'C'){
    screen.innerHTML = '0';
    currentScore = 0;
    currentAction = '';
    number = '';
    return
  }
  currentAction = operator;
  screen.innerHTML = operator;
  number = parseInt(number);
  currentScore += number;
  number = '';
  
}


const calculate = ()=> {
  switch (currentAction) {
    case '+':
      return currentScore + parseInt(number);
    case '-':
      return currentScore - parseInt(number);
    case '*':
      return currentScore * parseInt(number);
    case '/':
      return currentScore / parseInt(number);
  }
}
item.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (this.innerHTML == '=') {
      screen.innerHTML = calculate()
    }else{
      showResult(this.innerHTML)
    }
  });
});
```